# How to override the derived Eq instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, email-verification

I'm wondering why the [email-validate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/email-validate) package derives Eq in the following code:

```
data EmailAddress = EmailAddress ByteString ByteString
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Data, Typeable, Generic)
```

I mean, I was using `Text` for email addresses until I realised I need to make them case-insensitive (so i don't save `Example@ex.ample` and `example@ex.ample` as 2 different addresses), so i got to this library only to discover it derives `Eq`.

So, is it reasonable to derive `Eq` instead of a self-made case-insensitive instance?.
Also, if I were to use this library, how could I provide my own `Eq` instance for `EmailAdress`?

Comment: You might consider using a smart constructor that normalizes case rather than using the raw `EmailAddress` constructor.

Comment: @chepner ...or a bidirectional pattern synonym. Then can even pattern match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> So, is it reasonable to derive `Eq` instead of a self-made case-insensitive instance?

That sort of depends on what you want. I'm sure that the author of the package has their reasons for that `Eq` instance.

> Also, if i were to use this library, how could i provide my own `Eq` instance for `EmailAdress`?

You can't "override" their instance. The usual solution to this sort of problem is a `newtype` wrapper on which you write your own instances:

```
newtype MyEmailAddress = MyEmailAddress EmailAddress
```

And then you are free to define your own version of equality, possibly as:

```
import Data.Char (toLower)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as DBC (map)

instance Eq MyEmailAddress where
  MyEmailAddress (EmailAddress a1 d1) == MyEmailAddress (EmailAddress a2 d2) 
    = DBC.map toLower a1 == DBC.map toLower a2 && DBC.map toLower d1 == DBC.map toLower d2
```

---

While I'm at it, allow me to mention you can even define a pattern synonym which makes everything much nicer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
pattern Email address domain = MyEmailAddress (EmailAddress address domain)
```

Then, you can easily make one of your emails with `Email "yourName" "yourDomain"` as well as pattern match on that. The `Eq` instance looks a lot nicer with this:

```
instance Eq MyEmailAddress where
  Email a1 d1 == Email a2 d2 
    = DBC.map toLower a1 == DBC.map toLower a2 && DBC.map toLower d1 == DBC.map toLower d2
```

Comment: I'd add that you can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to keep any instances from `EmailAddress` you want.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I actually heavily debated whether I wanted to add something about that too. I think I won't because the OP has provided the full data definition of `EmailAddress` and there isn't anything from there you would want to lift using GND.